# not getting the main class in java

Tags: java

This is the code

```
package tut6;
abstract class Bank{
    public abstract void getbalance();
}

class BankA extends Bank{
    public void getbalance(){
        System.out.println("$100");
    }
}

class BankB extends Bank{
    public void getbalance(){
        System.out.println("$150");
    }
}

class BankC extends Bank{
    public void getbalance(){
        System.out.println("$200");
    }
}
public class bankmanagement{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BankA a = new BankA();
        a.getbalance();

        BankB b = new BankB();
        b.getbalance();

        BankC c = new BankC();
        c.getbalance();
    }
}
```

[error in the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rXmn.png)

cannot compile and run the java file from the terminal using javac and java. please can anyone help.

Comment: Do not attach stack traces as images. Copy-paste them as text to the question.

Comment: @Torben Not really. No answers there that match this problem.

Comment: You should be one directory up, and you should have issued `javac tut6/bankmanagement.java` and `java tut6.bankmanagement`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user207421 gave the correct answer in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78105743/not-getting-the-main-class-in-java#comment137697023_78105743), namely:

1. Navigate to this folder:

```
C:\Users\HP\Desktop\language\oopsinjava
```

2. Compile the Java source code with this command:
   (assuming that the code in your question is in a file named `bankmanagement.java`)

```
javac tut6\bankmanagement.java
```

3. Once the source code is successfully compiled, you can execute the compiled `bankmanagement` class with the following command (issued from the same directory as the `javac` command in the previous step):

```
java tut6.bankmanagement
```

Note that the above assumes that `javac.exe` and `java.exe` are on your [Windows] PATH (environment variable) which, according to the image you posted, appears that they are.

Refer to Oracle's [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html).

Comment: @user207421 maybe next time you'll post an answer rather than a comment. Is there some way I can transfer you the reputation points?

Comment: No. Enjoy. I stopped posting answers here about 5 years ago, for reasons that remain sufficient.